# how to send email in django

Tags: django, email

my settings in settings.py but not sending any mails to gmail account.
can u please expalin me how to send confirm mail to mail`enter code here`

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

I am getting success message in cmd but not sending email to my id

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            print(current_site)
            subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
            message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            from_email =settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            print(from_email,"email here")
            # to_email = [from_email,'sridharadhi50@gmail.com']
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            # user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In your python file

```
def get_email_connection():
 use_tls = True
 use_ssl = False
 fail_silently=False
 connection = get_connection(host=config.email_host, 
                        port=settings.EMAIL_PORT, 
                        username=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 
                        password=settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, 
                        use_tls=use_tls,
                        use_ssl=use_ssl,
            fail_silently=fail_silently)
 return connection



def signup(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        connection=get_email_connection()
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        print(current_site)
        subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
        message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        from_email =settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        print(from_email,"email here")
        # to_email = [from_email,'sridharadhi50@gmail.com']
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject, message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [to_email],connection=connection
        )
        email.send()
        # user.email_user(subject, message)
        return redirect('account_activation_sent')enter code here
```

Comment: thanks Aman trigunait. but it getting this NameError : global name 'get_connection' is not defined

Comment: django.core.mail import get_connection                                                                yes I can fix it.but still it's staying in same page it is not redirect to success page. i mean active page

Comment: django.core.mail import get_connection                                                                 data is stored in django backend but my gmail account not getting any email received and send.from addressabc@gmail.com to address if def@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You should give EMAIL_BACKEND

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

its work fine.

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
I am added that one. I am using my locahost for sending mail is it work or after hosting only it works