# How to send an email after 11 months from the last technical checkup last_checkup datefield()?

Tags: python, django, email, django-models

So I have built an awesome ticketing system for a company that makes GPS embedded chips. Once a year they service their products and I've made a model field last_checkup. After 11 months from the last checkup they need to get notified that soon they will have to do it again. Do you have any ideas how do I write a logic for that? Here is the code. Thanks. _/I_ They will later change the date so it works next year.

```
class tickets(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(devices, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)       
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    problem = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="authorname", null=True)
    executive = models.ForeignKey(executives, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    email_as_send = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    SLA = models.DateField()

    # Here is the question. They have yearly checkups of devices someone  buys. 
    # They need to be notified 11 months from the last checkup.

    last_checkup = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.problem

    def save(self):
        if self.status == True:
           send_mail("subject", 
           "Zatvoren ticket", 
           "jankojovicic351@gmail.com", 
           [self.author.email], fail_silently=False)
        super().save()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the combination of redis server( ps: see redis for linux and see memurai for windows) and celery package to schedule a task. You can send email by following this[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781574/how-to-send-email-in-django). Write email sendig task and schedule after every 11 months.

Comment: I've already coded sendmail method to send email when the ticket is opened and when its closed. But I'm having trouble scheduling it 11 months from now. I will check Redis out. Thanks.